# How to pass a list of lists of int to a c++ function from python with cytpes

Tags: c++, python-3.x, ctypes

I'm learning c++ (I've been learning for about 48 hours, so forgive the possible ignorance) for the purpose of speeding up some slow python code. I have written c++ function as follows;

```
std::tuple<float*, int*, int*, int**> scoreS(int**, float***, int**, float**, float**, float**, float**, float**, float**, float*, float**);
```

In my python file I do the following;

```
tmpScoreLib = cdll.LoadLibrary('/ScorerPT2.dll')
tmpScoreLib.ScoreSWrapped.argtypes = [POINTER(POINTER(c_int)), POINTER(POINTER(POINTER(c_float))), POINTER(POINTER(c_int)), POINTER(POINTER(c_float)), POINTER(POINTER(c_float)), POINTER(POINTER(c_float)), POINTER(POINTER(c_float)), POINTER(POINTER(c_float)), POINTER(POINTER(c_float)), POINTER(POINTER(c_float)), POINTER(POINTER(c_float))]

tmpvals1, tmpvals2, tmpvals3, tmpvals4 = tmpScoreLib.ScoreSWrapped(val1,val2,val3,val4,val5,val6,val7,val8,val9,val10,val11)
```

I use ScoreSWrapped as a wrapper function around the ScoreS function [as per this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22263380/c-linkage-function-cannot-return-c-class-error-resulting-from-the-contents-o).

However when I try and run this I get the following error:

```
ArgumentError: argument 1: <class 'TypeError'>: expected LP_LP_c_long instance instead of list
```

This is because val1 is a list of lists of floats rather than a pointer to a list of pointers to ints (**I assume?**) What I can't figure out is how to go from having a list of lists of ints in python to being able to pass the required int** to the c++ function. This is my first foray into this type of c++ wrapper so I could be doing multiple things wrong - assume total ignorance on my part! I have found other questions where they either user ctype.cast or ctypes.byref, but I can't really understand how to apply those.

Comment: There are a bunch of things wrong here. First: Check [\[SO\]: How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) or
[\[SO\]: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (reprex (mcve))](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
for more asking related details. Please create a minimal reproducible example. Then *CTypes* can't be used for ***C++*** types. And what's the 3 star pointers?

Comment: @CristiFati thanks for the input. I can't really add more code without making new code (the stuff within the function is long, convoluted and doesn't have any baring on the error. CTypes can't be used for c++ types? That's helpful, thanks. The 3 star pointers are 3D arrays, assuming I've set them up correctly(?). If there's a way I can improve the question, please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

You have to manually create the arrays to pass.  `ctypes` [supports this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#arrays), of course, but you can’t just supply a Python list.  For multidimensional arrays implemented as pointers to pointers, you’ll have to keep references around to every array at every level (to keep them alive) *and* copy their addresses into the “containing” array.

Finally, you can’t unpack a `std::tuple` using `ctypes`; you’ll have to make a custom structure **type** (or else return those values through yet more pointers).  It might be easier to do the conversion in C than to work everything into a `ctypes`-compatible form.